# Error: Main method not found in class mypackage.Mainclass, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a java application in eclipse but its showing

> Error: Main method not found in class mypackage.Mainclass, please define the main method as:   public static void main(String[] args)

even though it's included correctly:

```
package mypackage;

import javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException;
import javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException;
import javax.transaction.RollbackException;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Mainclass {
public static void main(String[] args) {  

       //creating configuration object  
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the         configuration file  

        //creating seession factory object  
        SessionFactory factory=cfg
            .buildSessionFactory();  

        //creating session object  
        Session session=factory.openSession();  

    //creating transaction object  
        Transaction t=(Transaction) session.beginTransaction();  

        Employee e1=new Employee();  
        e1.setId(115);  
        e1.setFirstName("sonoo");  
        `enter code here`e1.setLastName("jaiswal");  

    session.persist(e1);//persisting the object  

    try {
        t.commit();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//transaction is committed  
    session.close();  

    System.out.println("successfully saved");  
}
}
```

When I am clicking on Run As->Java Application, it's asking me to Select Java Application by showing a dialog box where my project name is not showing up.

Comment: Do you have compile Errors in your Project?

Comment: no compile errors ? do i have to set up any configurations before running the application in eclipse?

Comment: I think I had to set up a run configuration properly that I did the above problem got solved

Comment: Please take a look at the linked question... did you define your own String class? Does the problem still exist when you use `java.lang.String[]` in the main method definition?

Comment: no i didnt..no the problem is resovled now

Comment: Then post the answer and accept it, or delete the question.